# Issue using classicthesis, auto-pst-pdf, and hyperref. Possible conflict involving chapter headings

Tags: hyperref, incompatibility, classicthesis, auto-pst-pdf

Here is a simple recreation of the problem:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}         
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[runs=2]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{subfig}  
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

%\chapter{Test Chapter} % This line causes the problem

\blindtext

\begin{figure}[htbp]
 \centering
  \scriptsize
  \psfrag{LS-DYNA keyword deck by LS-PrePost}{}
  \psfrag{Nodal Temperature Data}{\small Knotentemperaturen in ^{\circ}\mathrm{C}}
  \psfrag{Time}{\small Zeit in s}
  \psfragfig[width=0.70\textwidth,keepaspectratio,angle=-90]{timestep_001.eps}
  \caption{Figure from LS-PrePost}
  \label{fig:prepost}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

If `\Chapter{}` is removed then everything is fine but obviously there is no chapter heading:

[image: with chapters]

If `\Chapter{}` is left in then then the heading is there but the figure is not generated properly:

[image: without chapters]

This only occurs with with the `hyperref` package loaded.

There seems to be a conflict that arises from using `classicthesis`, `auto-pst-pdf`, and `hyperref` together. What is the cause and is there a way around it?

The .eps file for this example can be downloaded [here](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/download/file.php?id=6353&sid=e8841389f25aaf10e516b3df4b9332d6).

I'm using TexWorks compiling with: `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex`

Comment: Please note that package `subfig` doesn't work that good with `hyperref` and should be replaced by `subcaption`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems this can be resolved by not loading the `hyperref` package, it's included by `classicthesis` anyway.